# Is CSS Grid Using Regular CSS Under the Hood?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I have been wondering if CSS Grid is completely new functionality to the CSS language, or if it is essentially syntactic sugar - aka is grid just using the CSS that predated it under the hood. Can everything in CSS grid essentially be done using plain CSS?

Comment: under what hood? CSS is not a programming language ... don't think it's like jQuery is built above Javascript

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well, Firefox has an about:config entry named `layout.css.emulate-moz-box-with-flex`, so it can make you wonder, can't it. What other features could there be that just emulate other features.

Comment: @MrLister Yes but I don't think when implementing they will use other features, I mean Firefox or other browser will not first change Flexbox or CSS grid with other features (inline-block, float, etc) and then simply implement them. This logic is more for programming language where we build a library using some basic functions and we can use that library to built a bigger one, and so on.